# Right click stop Propagation not workling

Tags: jquery

I want to rightclick and disable something on rightclick on my div.

Sadly the right click is not capured by StopPropagation and the right click menu of the browser is still shown...

```
$("#PresentationFilterBigDiv").mousedown(function (ev) {
    if (ev.which == 3) {
        $('#PresentationFilterDiv').css('display', 'block');
        $('#PresentationFilterBigDiv').css('display', 'none');
        ev.stopPropagation();
        presentationMode = 1;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: ev.preventDefault(); This is what you might be looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try using `oncontextmenu` and `event.preventDefault();`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  document.oncontextmenu = function() {
    return false;
  };

  $(document).mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.which == 2 ) {
      alert('No don\'t use right mousebutton!'); 
      return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the mukltiple edit but know i'm not sure they were relevant :(

Comment: It turn it back to the original

Comment: @A.Wolff That's okay buddy... Yours will work too... Ha ha.